# How do I embedd an audio player in a PHP page?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am begginer to PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript developement.  I have one link by the name 49(doc file),and audio file name 49(mp3file name).  I'd like the audio file to play one time when the link to the doc file is clicked.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed doc files in IFrame's, if Office is installed on the client's computer, I think. However that is a terrible solution either way. If it has to be a document, make it a PDF so most of your users can view it.

As for an MP3, you can use the [Easy Musicplayer for Flash](http://emff.sourceforge.net/) to set up a playing facility. It has an autostart function so you might be able to put together a mechanism that allows the mp3 start at the same time the user clicks on a link.

Maybe, though, there is a better solution for your task. Post more details, somebody will probably come up with a HTML based solution.

Other than that, accepting a dead line in a line of work you don't know nothing about is never clever.

Comment: Hi good afternoon,actually i am working php,emef player is not working after adding that html code genarator in pages..also i extraxted that player but its not working

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on your question. If I'm not right, try rephrasing the question (edit the question, don't [post a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667190/beginner-to-php-mysql-javascript-development)).

Sounds like you have two links that are being served up by a php file:

```
<a href="download.php?file-name=49.doc">49.doc</a>
<a href="download.php?file-name=49.mp3">49.mp3</a>
```

And when you click on the Mp3, it doesn't play?

If so, then you'll want to read about the Content-type HTTP header (look at php's `header()` function). Web browsers use the file's content type to determine what kind of file it is.

Is this a homework question?

Comment: I think he wants the mp3 being played when somebody clicks on the doc file. All there is to it is some probably pretty simple JavaScript. I would post the solution, if I just knew that language better ;)